# Is there a term for something equally distributed around zero?

Tags: definition

Let's say X is uniformly distributed in [-1 , 1]

Then what can we call the distribution of X³ ? It is not uniform, but it "mirrors" around 0 as well.

Is there a simple word describing X³ that would also apply to X⁵   and to  3X, for example?

I would call it "mirror around zero" but I find this ugly and was wondering if there's a better and established term.

Comment: Saying the distribution is "symmetric" about 0 is probably the best you can do with one word.  This implies that 0 is the median, but it is a stronger condition than merely requiring 0 to be the median.

Comment: Good suggestion, it fits perfectly for my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the OP's comment, saying the distribution is "symmetric about zero" is a suitable phrase.